# Custom navigational properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Suppose we have a table **Car** in a database that looks like this:

```
Id | Brand | Model | Color | Description
 1 |  23   |  6    |  005  | Beautiful car
```

And another table called **Metadata** that contains different information about a car.

```
Id | Type  | Key | Value
 1 | Brand |   6 | Ford
 2 | Brand |  22 | BMW
 3 | Brand |  23 | Audi
 4 | Model |   5 | Focus
 5 | Model |   6 | A4
 6 | Model |   7 | 325
 7 | Color | 005 | Black
 8 | Color | 019 | Blue
```

As you can see, the combination Type & Key should be unique in the table and could be considered the foreign key.

I fully understand the concept of normalizing a database. In our case normalizing the `Metadata` table would introduce complexities in other parts in the application I can't get into which is why we're trying it this way.

The Code First classes `Car` and `Metadata` look like this

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BrandId { get; set; }
    public string ModelId { get; set; }
    public string ColorId { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration classes for `Car` and `Metadata`

```
public class CarMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Car>
{
    this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
    this.Property(t => t.BrandId).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(6);
    this.Property(t => t.ModelId).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(6);
    this.Property(t => t.ColorId).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(6);

    this.ToTable("Car");
    this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
    this.Property(t => t.BrandId).HasColumnName("Brand");
    this.Property(t => t.ModelId).HasColumnName("Model");
    this.Property(t => t.ColorId).HasColumnName("Color");
}

public class MetadataMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Metadata>
{
    this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
    this.Property(t => t.Type).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(6);
    this.Property(t => t.Key).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(6);
    this.Property(t => t.Value).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(6);

    this.ToTable("Metadata");
    this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
    this.Property(t => t.Type).HasColumnName("Type");
    this.Property(t => t.Key).HasColumnName("Key");
    this.Property(t => t.Value).HasColumnName("Value");
}
```

And a `DbContext`

```
public class CarContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Metadata> Metadata { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CarMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MetadataMap());
    }
}
```

A method to retrieve the first 10 cars

```
public List<Car> GetAllCars()
{
    using (CarContext context = new CarContext())
    {
        return context.Cars.ToList();
    }
}
```

Suppose I add navigational properties to the `Car` class

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string BrandId { get; set; }
    public virtual Metadata Brand { get; set; }

    public string ModelId { get; set; }
    public virtual Metadata Model { get; set; }

    public string ColorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Metadata Color { get; set; }
}
```

What is the most elegant and efficient way to make sure these properties are materialized when **GetAllCars()** is called?

Comment: Look at specifying `[ForeignKey]` attribute? (Alternatively you can specify the navigation property in your fluent definition).

Comment: How many different metadata are there in real life?

Comment: @GertArnold About 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you could have "real" navigation properties in this case, since I don't see how you could define this relationship in the database and/or use fluent API to map it in the code. (someone might correct me here).

In this case I would define these as not mapped and populate them in your `GetAllCars()` method. So, the `Car` class would look like this:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string BrandId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Metadata Brand { get; set; }

    public string ModelId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Metadata Model { get; set; }

    public string ColorId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Metadata Color { get; set; }
}
```

And, the method would be:

```
public List<Car> GetAllCars()
{
    using (CarContext context = new CarContext())
    {
        var returnList = new List<Car>();

        foreach(var car in context.Cars)
        {
            car.Brand = context.Metadata
                               .Where(x => x.Key == car.BrandId && x.Type == "Brand")
                               .FirstOrDefault();

            car.Model = context.Metadata
                               .Where(x => x.Key == car.ModelId && x.Type == "Model")
                               .FirstOrDefault();

            car.Color = context.Metadata
                               .Where(x => x.Key == car.ColorId && x.Type == "Color")
                               .FirstOrDefault();

            returnList.Add(car);
        }

        return returnList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to foreach over the collection and materialize each property individually.

Comment: Even if EF had something for this case, `foreach` would have happened implicitly. You'd just feel better because you wouldn't see it ;) If you are able to specify the relationship in the database, EF could be able to generate the SQL that would bring all the data in one go, but without the relationship `foreach` has to happen one way or another. You could, however, create a view in the database, or a stored procedure and then query/execute that using EF.

Comment: I like that idea of creating a view. Thank you!